# Unique function C++ <vector>

Tags: c++

```
    sort(x.begin(),x.end());
x.erase(unique(x.begin(),x.end()),x.end());
```

this code is supposed to rearrange the order of vector by ascending order and remove duplicated numbers

** The code has nothing wrong it's working

I want to know in

```
x.erase(unique(x.begin(),x.end()),x.end());
```

what are those parameters isn't erase function just remove the specified index ?

Comment: Here is the [cppreference page for erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase). As you can see, erase has one form for removing elements in a range `[first, last)`.

Comment: Also http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/

Comment: Wow apparently people didn't like this question ~_~. Next time I recommend trying to google it first.

Comment: @quasiverse  I did but couldn't understand So I said why don't ask other people. anyway they never like any question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using the second form  <sub>[Removes the elements in the range [first, last)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase).</sub> of `std::vector::erase`

Here, `std::unique` returns new end of the range after removing all consecutive duplicates in *[first, last)*